# separating a string in to 3 different string variables in java

Tags: java, string, date, split, substring

I have a String variable as a date type.for example: 
`String myDate= "20130403";`
and I want to separate it to 3 different date formats like this:

```
String myDay = "03";
String myMonth= "04";
String myYear= "2013";
```

how is the fastest way to separate my String?

thanks

Comment: Given that you've used a tag of "substring" that means you know the operation exists... so it's not clear why you're not just using it...

Comment: If you want to pick up girls, you can use a regex such as `(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})`. Otherwise, String.substring should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a fixed format simply use substring.

```
    String myDate= "20130403";
    String myYear = myDate.substring(0,4);
    String myMonth= myDate.substring(4,6);
    String myDay= myDate.substring(6,8);

    System.out.println(myDay);
    System.out.println(myMonth);
    System.out.println(myYear);
```

Comment: This is all wrong for the input string        String myDay = myDate.substring(0,4);
    String myMonth= myDate.substring(4,6);
    String myYear= myDate.substring(6,8);

Answer (score 6):

```
String yourDateString = "20130403";
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date currentDate = sd.parse(yourDateString);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(currentDate);
String year = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "";

// As Gyro said month start at 0 to 11.
String month = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "";  

String day = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "";
```

Comment: Nope, this will give the wrong answer for the month, and it's using string concatenation for no reason. (Use `String.valueOf` as a cleaner way of converting.) Even after fixing those issues, you'll end up with a one-digit string for January to September or for a day less than 10. Basically, this isn't what's been asked for. It wouldn't even get the sample string in the question right.

Comment: Should be `cal.setTime(currentDate);`

Comment: Plus, it gives "3" for the day, not "03". But anyway, using SimpleDateFormat is a good idea.

Comment: Also note that months are zero based in `Calendar`, so you would yield "3" for April :-(

Answer (score 3):

If you know for sure that your date comes with such format `yyyyMMdd` then you can use [`subString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) function for this

```
String myDate = "20120221"

String year = myDate.subString(0,4);
String month = myDate.subString(4,6);
String day = myDate.subString(6);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to parse your String as date and, using Calendar, get all fields you want.

```
    String myDate= "20130403";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(myDate));

        String myDay = (String)cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        String myMonth = (String)(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
        String myYear = (String)cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use substring if your data string format isn't going to change:

```
String myDate= "20130403";

String myDay = myDate.substring(6,8);
String myMonth = myDate.substring(4,6);
String myYear = myDate.substring(0,4);
```

Comment: Substring end-indexes are exclusive, not inclusive.

Comment: @JonSkeet changed my mistake

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd like to use special [java simple date format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this.

Answer (score 2):

If the string has a fixed length (e.g the year is always 4 digits, the month is always 2, etc) you can use the substring() method.

In your case:

```
String myDate = "20130403";
String myYear = myDate.substring(0,4);
String myMonth = myDate.substring(4,6);
String myDay = myDate.substring(6,8);
```

If the string is not fixed length you may try using a delimiter e.g "-". So your string looks like this "2013-04-03" and then simply use the String.split(); function.

Example:

```
String myDate = "2013-04-03";
String[] myDateElements = myDate.split("-");
String myYear = myDateElements[0];
String myMonth = myDateElements[1];
String myDay = myDateElements[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you try substring ? like this (best way i think and fastest too) :

```
@Test
final public void testStringDateOperation() {
    final String myDate= "20130403";
  final String year = myDate.substring(0, 4);
    final String month = myDate.substring(4, 6);
    final String day = myDate.substring(6, 8);
    Logger.trace("year: {0} - month: {1} - day: {2}", year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

substring might perform the task, but is not the fastest way.
Substring creates new string object for all the tokens, hence not performance efficient or the fastest way. below is the source code for subString() from java src.

```
public String More ...substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
 if (beginIndex < 0) {
     throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
 }
 if (endIndex > count) {
     throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
 }
 if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
     throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
 }
 return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
     **new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);**
```

}

so, the best way is to, split using the regEx according to me.

regards
Punith